# SSL enabled Web Site can't connect to Local C# Web Socket Server

Tags: c#, html, ssl, websocket

I'm using a [local web socket server implemented in C#](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck). Its working fine when I connect to hosted html page without SSL, but when there is SSL enabled, Web socket connection closed automatically.

In the readMe.txt file of the library, it says to attach a certification file. 
Here is how I create and attach the file. Right click the Project and do Sign the Manifest and gave a password. Then I have set the `Certification` property as follows.

```
WebSocketServer server = new WebSocketServer("wss://0.0.0.0:8431");
string path = "C:\\Users\\Dehan\\Documents\\MySolutionName\\";
server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(path+"certificateName.pfx", "certificate_pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {                        
                   //inside onopen
                };

                socket.OnError = error =>
                {
                    //inside onerror
                };

                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                   //inside onclose
                };

                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                 //inside onmessage
                }

           });
```

[image: Html page]

[image]

following code shows the javascript of the html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start = function () {
        var inc = document.getElementById('incomming');
        var wsImpl = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
        var form = document.getElementById('sendForm');
        var input = document.getElementById('sendText');

        inc.innerHTML += "connecting to server ..<br/>";

        // create a new websocket and connect
        window.ws = new wsImpl('wss://127.0.0.1:8431/');

        // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            inc.innerHTML += evt.data + '<br/>';
        };

        // when the connection is established, this method is called
        ws.onopen = function () {
            inc.innerHTML += '.. connection open<br/>';
        };

        // when the connection is closed, this method is called
        ws.onclose = function () {
            inc.innerHTML += '.. connection closed<br/>';
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var val = input.value;
            ws.send(val);
            input.value = "";
        });

    }
    window.onload = start;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(path+"certificateName.pfx", "certificate_pwd", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

In the above line of code, If you're using a self signed certificate make sure that it is added to your computers trusted root authorities.